# Python/Django Check if object is in 2 lists

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Profiles have tags.
I'm rendering a list of `profile_tags` and `top_tags`. How would I go about checking if each tag in top_tags is in profile_tags?

What I've tried in my views:

```
has_tag = False
profile_tags = profile.tags.all()
top_tags = Tag.objects.all()
for top in top_tags:
    if top in profile_tags:
        has_tag = True
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
has_tag = set(list(top_tags)).issubset(list(profile_tags))
```

This gives you the boolean flag.

Comment: `list()` returns a `list` not a boolean value, and your new edit makes your solution exactly same as mine.

Comment: I'm given a TypeError:'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: sorry.. the `list()` wrap was my mistake.

Comment: @karthikr When rendering to the template: I have `{% if has_tag %}Remove{% else %}Add{% endif %}`. But it seems to never hit the else to show `'Remove'`. Would you know how to make the check work?

Comment: check the value of `has_tag` - the template should go by the default `True` or `False` boolean. One way to check is - just do `{{has_tag}}` and see the value

Comment: @karthikr I'm sorry that's still confusing for me. I understand `{{ has_tag }}` would return a boolean value. But it doesn't in the template. I guess what I'm asking is, where does the `if` part of things come into the scenario? As to say, if its true or if it's false

Comment: @karthikr i'm rendering `context['has_tag'] = has_tag` to the template

Comment: well.. what you are doing is right `{% if has_tag %}Remove{% else %}Add{% endif %}` would check if has_tag is present or not, and show the result. One more thing I would check is if has_tag is indeed True, or False - do a `print` and check  on the console

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28333/discussion-between-modelesq-and-karthikr)

Answer (score 1):

Convert both of them to sets and check if set of `top_tags` is a **subset** of set of `profile_tags`:

```
In [14]: profile_tags=[1,2,3,4]

In [15]: top_tags=[1,2,3]

In [16]: s1=set(profile_tags)

In [17]: s2=set(top_tags)

In [18]: s2.issubset(s1)
Out[18]: True
```